# Making a network by using predetermined XY coordinates and using degree of correlation as edge colors in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, networking, igraph, correlation

I have this correlation matrix:

```
> head(cmat)
          1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8         9
1 1.0000000 0.3811486 0.4635226 0.4388138 0.4702924 0.3839215 0.3952252 0.3933645 0.4020303
2 0.3811486 1.0000000 0.4636466 0.3449465 0.4185577 0.4400996 0.3995343 0.4683042 0.4534727
3 0.4635226 0.4636466 1.0000000 0.3665173 0.5041320 0.4763060 0.4090055 0.4126498 0.3903248
4 0.4388138 0.3449465 0.3665173 1.0000000 0.4449320 0.4125759 0.4388138 0.3030503 0.3493223
         10        11        12        13        14        15        16        17        18
1 0.4839340 0.4947885 0.4633059 0.4290341 0.4504393 0.4647089 0.4816216 0.4294152 0.4666731
2 0.4045505 0.4036112 0.4377636 0.3849775 0.3769241 0.4767528 0.4546915 0.4036112 0.3467831
3 0.5536620 0.4321896 0.4743869 0.5002220 0.4836144 0.5319749 0.4907812 0.4631280 0.3625720
4 0.4323536 0.4244193 0.4486245 0.4213758 0.4462888 0.4425709 0.4692482 0.3726047 0.3670268
         19        20
1 0.3664227 0.4027118
2 0.3041602 0.3468899
3 0.4152681 0.3361121 
4 0.2086564 0.3833584
```

I also have the coordinates of each of these 20 items as dataframe:

```
> head(coordinates)
       X       Y
1 19.908 250.861
2  6.767 253.552
3 18.280 264.838
4 31.000 263.078
5 42.900 271.389
6 54.495 269.625
```

What I'd like to do is to plot these coordinates as points, as such:

```
ggplot(coordinates, aes(X, Y))+
  geom_point()
```

but then also draw connection lines between each of these points, where the color or thickness of the line corresponds to the relative value in the correlation matrix `cmat`.

I looked into the `igraph` package but I only managed to display a network with custom coordinates:

```
g <- graph.data.frame(cmat)
l <- as.matrix(coordinates)

plot(g,layout=l,rescale=T,axes=TRUE)
```

and it also assign the correlation values to each cell instead.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Is it correct that your igraph does everything that you want _except_ for coloring the edges?

Comment: Not really: I'm not sure what it actually does, as it produces a plot that is quite confusing, numbers overlapping and all.. I believe the only thing I got right is setting the layout.

Comment: Without your data,  we can't see what you see nor can we adjust it.  Please run `dput(cmat)` and `dput(coordinates)` and paste the results into your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to apply to your exact case as we're missing your exact data. Suppose you would like to do something like that to the `mtcars` dataset, we could use the `ggraph` package to make plotting network graphs easier.

We're assuming the `mpg` and `wt` variables of the dataset are the XY coordinates.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(igraph)
library(ggraph)

data <- as.matrix(mtcars)

cor <- cor(t(apply(data, 2, scale)))

graph <- graph.adjacency(cor, weighted = TRUE)

ggraph(graph, layout = data[, c("mpg", "wt")]) +
  geom_edge_link(aes(colour = weight)) +
  geom_node_point() +
  scale_edge_color_gradient2()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-01-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

If we'd want to do a similar thing in vanilla ggplot2, you'd have to construct the edges manually.

```r
cor_df <- reshape2::melt(cor)
cor_df <- transform(
  cor_df,
  x = data[Var1, "mpg"],
  xend = data[Var2, "mpg"],
  y = data[Var1, "wt"],
  yend = data[Var2, "wt"]
)
ggplot(mtcars) +
  geom_segment(aes(x, y, xend = xend, yend = yend, colour = value),
               data = cor_df) +
  geom_point(aes(mpg, wt)) +
  scale_colour_gradient2()
```

[image]